# Can I use Bounty to drain my food?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kashrus of Paper Towels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/kashrus-of-paper-towels)

Using paper towels such as [bounty](http://www.bountytowels.com/) can be very useful when on a diet for draining the oil off of foods.

However, I heard rumors that bounty is made with non-kosher ingredients. Does this cause a problem when using it with food?